# Body changes its position after adding joint to it in Box2D in C++

Tags: c++, box2d

When I create a joint between two bodies, their position changes. I don't create any forces.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Box2D/Box2D.h>

int main() {
    // WORLD
    b2World world(b2Vec2(0, 0));

    // BODY DEF
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;

    // SHAPES
    b2PolygonShape polygonShape;
    polygonShape.SetAsBox(1, 1);

    b2PolygonShape polygonShape2;
    polygonShape2.SetAsBox(0.5, 0.5);

    // BODY 1
    b2Body* body = world.CreateBody(&bodyDef);
    b2Fixture* fixture = body->CreateFixture(&polygonShape, 1);

    // BODY 2
    b2Body* body2 = world.CreateBody(&bodyDef);
    b2Fixture* fixture2 = body2->CreateFixture(&polygonShape2, 1);

    // JOINT
    b2RevoluteJointDef jointDef;
    jointDef.bodyA = body;
    jointDef.localAnchorB.SetZero();

    jointDef.bodyB = body2;
    jointDef.localAnchorA.Set(1, 1);
    b2Joint* joint = world.CreateJoint(&jointDef);

    // LOGS (X POSITION)
    std::cout << "[ body 1 ] " << body->GetPosition().x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[ body 2 ] " << body2->GetPosition().x << std::endl;

    world.Step(1 / 50.0f, 8, 3);

    std::cout << "[ body 1 ] " << body->GetPosition().x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[ body 2 ] " << body2->GetPosition().x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output (`x position`):

```
[ body 1 ] 0                                (before step)
[ body 2 ] 0
[ body 1 ] -0.2                             (after step)
[ body 2 ] 0.8
```

I think it should return

```
[ body 1 ] 0                                (before step)
[ body 2 ] 0
[ body 1 ] 0                                (after step)
[ body 2 ] 1
```

Maybe something's wrong in my code? I'm new in Box2D. What I should do to get the expected result?

Before the step the position of `body 1` and `body 2` is `(0, 0)`. I think it should place body 2 to `(1, 1)` automatically after the step, it shouldn't move both bodies.

Comment: At > 100 rep, you should know that you're supposed to post code, not links to code.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'll try to decrease the lines of code and post it here, but I don't know stackoverflow will accept it.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks.

Comment: Added body2->SetTransform(body->GetPosition() + joint->GetAnchorA(), body2->GetAngle()); before calling `world.Step`. It places the second body on its correct position. If it isn't correct, 'invicible' force moves it to its correct position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not setting the `b2BodyDef` `position` field, so both bodies are getting created with their centers at the default location of `Vec2(0, 0)` (per the `b2BodyDef` structure definition in the `b2Body.h` file). Based on the positions that your code sets `localAnchorA` and `localAnchorB` to, I suspect your code for creating the bodies needs to be more like:

```
b2BodyDef bodyDef1;
bodyDef1.type = b2_dynamicBody;
bodyDef1.position.Set(0.0f, 0.0f);

b2BodyDef bodyDef2;
bodyDef2.type = b2_dynamicBody;
bodyDef2.position.Set(1.0f, 1.0f);
...
b2Body* body = world.CreateBody(&bodyDef1);
...
b2Body* body2 = world.CreateBody(&bodyDef2);
```

This way your `body` `polygonShape` is centered at `Vec2(0.0f, 0.0f)`, your `body2` `polygonShape2` is centered at the former shape's top right corner, and the *anchor point* that joins both bodies is right there at that same corner (the world position of `Vec2(1.0f, 1.0f)`).